# What's the best practice on async message handling

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm implementing a websocket messaging client with netty and java8. Each message has a transactionId, correlate to its response.

I need to implement a send API. So I have a few options.

1. send(message, Callback);
2. CompletableFuture send(message);

Either way, I'm thinking to have a transaction map(hashmap), which contains transactionId to Callback or CompletableFuture mapping. 
My question is which one is a better practice? Or something else? 
Is it OK to put CompletableFuture into Map?

***Any good design to solve a similar problem?***

Comment: Stick the `CompletableFuture` in the `Map`, this is perfectly safe.

Comment: There is no such thing as best practice.

Answer (score -1):

You can go either RabbitMQ or Apache Kafka.

1) RabbitMQ:
   To handle small data async messaging.It is not scalable as it required extra plugin.
   Message Speed: 10K/Sec

1) Apache Kafka:
   To handle Large data async messaging.It is scalable.
   Message Speed: 1000K/Sec.

Comment: OP "_I would like to receive websocket messages in a Java application_". This post "_here are two irrelevant technologies and that don't handle websockets_".